# Can I earn points for Accor if I book with booking.com?

Tags: loyalty-programs, booking.com

If I use booking.com website to book a room at Novotel (which is part of Accor chain), can I still earn points for Accor Le Club loyalty program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t earn points as mentioned on [Accor's website](https://www.accorhotels.com/gb/leclub/earn/earn-points.shtml) made through travel sites:

> Bookings made through online travel sites do not allow you to earn points on your stays.